# Outlook 365 VBA to access entries in a group mailbox contact list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I don't know if this is possible but I want to insert into the To of an email, an entry from the contacts part of a group mailbox address book.
I have managed to find the code to show the contact list in a separate dialog using this code:

```
Sub ShowSharedMailboxContacts()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
   ' Access the Outlook namespace
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Replace "SharedMailboxEmail@domain.com" with the shared mailbox email address
    Set objRecip = objNS.CreateRecipient("SharedMailboxEmail@domain.com")
    objRecip.Resolve

    If objRecip.Resolved Then
        ' Access the contacts folder of the shared mailbox
        Set objFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderContacts)
        objFolder.Display
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to resolve recipient."
    End If

   ' Clean up objects
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objRecip = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Even showing the address book `To` into a contact would be an improvement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.